# DNS setup on a VPS. Should I change something on the domaine registrar?

Tags: dns, domain, vps

I installed a DNS server on my VPS running Windows 2012 server. I created ns1.mydomain.com and ns2.mydomain.com pointing to the vps ip address.
Now do I have to change something on the  domain registrar ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you need to contact the registrar and tell them to list `ns1.mydomain.com` and `ns2.mydomain.com` as the nameservers for your domain (`mydomain.com`)

That said, I would advise against having all of your nameservers pointing to the same VPS. If anything happens to that VPS, your entire domain will go down. You should at the very least get a second VPS hosted in a different datacenter for `ns2.mydomain.com` if you need any sort of redundancy; If you're just trying to set something up to play around with and experiement with the DNS system and how it works, by all means just have fun with your VPS :)

Comment: In the registrar website there is a place where I can change the ns records. For now I'am setting a testing environment...but yes a redundancy is something I am gonna setup eventually. Thanks

Comment: For the redundancy, my vps is my dns also, and if the vps is down the dns also is down...I guess I should have the dns server outside of my vps ?